# Admob on ios crash

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, admob

### Issue

I am having an issue on iOS with the adMob pod. 
On Android everything works fine.
On iOS I get the following error when trying to call `firebase.admob()` :

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Error: Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed natively on your iOS project by calling firebase.admob().

Ensure you have the required Firebase iOS SDK pod for this module included in your Podfile, in this instance confirm you've added "pod 'Firebase/AdMob'" to your Podfile

See http://invertase.link/ios for full setup instructions.

This error is located at:
    in Loading (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:57)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at index.js:26)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at index.js:18)
    in StatusBarWarpper (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at index.js:26)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at index.js:18)
    in StatusBarWarpper (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
```

As a wild guess for the `react-native-track-player` library I had to

```
 Install react-native-swift to configure your iOS project to use the module correctly
After installing it, you will need to link it. Requires project to use Swift 4.2
```

https://react-native-kit.github.io/react-native-track-player/install/

I also tried to remove my `node_modules`, `pod install`,`pod update` and delete the `.lock` but nothing made any change.

---

### Project Files

#### React native

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "postinstall": "cd tools && sh ./postYarn.sh && sh ./patchReact.sh",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lottie-react-native": "^2.5.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "~4.3.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.11.17",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.14",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.25",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-largelist-v2": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-settings-list": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-spring-scrollview": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-swift": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-track-player": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-xml2js": "^1.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
    "tcomb-form-native": "0.6.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
    "flow-bin": "^0.89.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./resources/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "isSwift": true
}
```

#### iOS

`ios/Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'xxx' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path =>  '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'
  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'lottie-ios', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-ios'
  pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'

  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.40'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.40'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.40'

  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'

  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.5'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.4'

  pod 'react-native-background-timer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-timer'

  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

  target 'xxx-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

  target 'xxxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end

# target 'xxx-tvOS' do
#   # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
#   # use_frameworks!

#   # Pods for xxx-tvOS

#   target 'xxx-tvOSTests' do
#     inherit! :search_paths
#     # Pods for testing
#   end

# end
```

`podfile.lock`:

```
PODS:
  - Bolts (1.9.0):
    - Bolts/AppLinks (= 1.9.0)
    - Bolts/Tasks (= 1.9.0)
  - Bolts/AppLinks (1.9.0):
    - Bolts/Tasks
  - Bolts/Tasks (1.9.0)
  - BVLinearGradient (2.5.3):
    - React
  - Crashlytics (3.10.9):
    - Fabric (~> 1.7.13)
  - Fabric (1.7.13)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (4.40.0):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (4.40.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
  - FBSDKShareKit (4.40.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
  - Firebase/AdMob (5.3.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 7.31.0)
  - Firebase/Auth (5.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (= 5.0.1)
  - Firebase/Core (5.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.0.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (5.3.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 5.0.4)
  - Firebase/Database (5.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (= 5.0.1)
  - Firebase/Messaging (5.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 3.0.2)
  - Firebase/Storage (5.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseStorage (= 3.0.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseAuth (5.0.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseCore (5.0.4):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
  - FirebaseDatabase (5.0.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.18)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (3.1.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
  - FirebaseMessaging (3.0.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseStorage (3.0.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.31.0)
  - GoogleSignIn (4.4.0):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.2.0):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.0)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.2.0)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.2.0):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.0)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.2.0)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.0)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.2.0)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.2.0)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.2.0)"
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.2.1)
  - leveldb-library (1.20)
  - lottie-ios (2.5.0)
  - lottie-react-native (2.5.11):
    - lottie-ios
    - React
  - nanopb (0.3.901):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.901)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.901)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.901)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.901)
  - Protobuf (3.7.0)
  - QBImagePickerController (3.4.0)
  - React (0.55.4):
    - React/Core (= 0.55.4)
  - react-native-background-timer (2.1.1):
    - React
  - react-native-fbsdk (0.8.0):
    - React
    - react-native-fbsdk/Core (= 0.8.0)
    - react-native-fbsdk/Login (= 0.8.0)
    - react-native-fbsdk/Share (= 0.8.0)
  - react-native-fbsdk/Core (0.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - React
  - react-native-fbsdk/Login (0.8.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - React
  - react-native-fbsdk/Share (0.8.0):
    - FBSDKShareKit
    - React
  - React/Core (0.55.4):
    - yoga (= 0.55.4.React)
  - React/fishhook (0.55.4)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTAnimation (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTBlob (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTGeolocation (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTImage (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTNetwork
  - React/RCTLinkingIOS (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTNetwork (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTSettings (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTText (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTVibration (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTWebSocket (0.55.4):
    - React/Core
    - React/fishhook
    - React/RCTBlob
  - RNDeviceInfo (0.21.5):
    - React
  - RNFS (2.13.3):
    - React
  - RNImageCropPicker (0.23.0):
    - QBImagePickerController
    - React/Core
    - RSKImageCropper
  - RSKImageCropper (2.2.1)
  - yoga (0.55.4.React)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - BVLinearGradient (from `../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient`)
  - Crashlytics (~> 3.10.4)
  - Fabric (~> 1.7.5)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (= 4.40)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.40)
  - FBSDKShareKit (= 4.40)
  - Firebase/AdMob (~> 5.3.0)
  - Firebase/Auth (~> 5.3.0)
  - Firebase/Core (~> 5.3.0)
  - Firebase/Database (~> 5.3.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (~> 5.3.0)
  - Firebase/Storage (~> 5.3.0)
  - GoogleSignIn
  - lottie-ios (from `../node_modules/lottie-ios`)
  - lottie-react-native (from `../node_modules/lottie-react-native`)
  - react-native-background-timer (from `../node_modules/react-native-background-timer`)
  - react-native-fbsdk (from `../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk`)
  - React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTGeolocation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTImage (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTLinkingIOS (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTNetwork (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTSettings (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTText (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - RNDeviceInfo (from `../node_modules/react-native-device-info`)
  - RNFS (from `../node_modules/react-native-fs`)
  - RNImageCropPicker (from `../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker`)
  - yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec`)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Bolts
    - Crashlytics
    - Fabric
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - FBSDKShareKit
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseDatabase
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - FirebaseStorage
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
    - GoogleSignIn
    - GoogleToolboxForMac
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - leveldb-library
    - nanopb
    - Protobuf
    - QBImagePickerController
    - RSKImageCropper

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  BVLinearGradient:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient"
  lottie-ios:
    :path: "../node_modules/lottie-ios"
  lottie-react-native:
    :path: "../node_modules/lottie-react-native"
  React:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native"
  react-native-background-timer:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-background-timer"
  react-native-fbsdk:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk"
  RNDeviceInfo:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-device-info"
  RNFS:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-fs"
  RNImageCropPicker:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker"
  yoga:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Bolts: ac6567323eac61e203f6a9763667d0f711be34c8
  BVLinearGradient: 0d985ec461359c82bc254f26d11008bdae50d17a
  Crashlytics: 55e24fc23989680285a21cb1146578d9d18e432c
  Fabric: 25d0963b691fc97be566392243ff0ecef5a68338
  FBSDKCoreKit: ae214474b25033399c131dc81d258e412582a2ba
  FBSDKLoginKit: 7a1e411d46acc8834588eca437daf34de42e1d52
  FBSDKShareKit: 0e45916f4150da485928ae2a17ca021950b194f5
  Firebase: 68afeeb05461db02d7c9e3215cda28068670f4aa
  FirebaseAnalytics: b3628aea54c50464c32c393fb2ea032566e7ecc2
  FirebaseAuth: 463b8ce33bd5d05f706dcd4615499e3212b4132b
  FirebaseCore: 62f1b792a49bb9e8b4073f24606d2c93ffc352f0
  FirebaseDatabase: 482bad9c2abd422bb2321194fb8c937e67426a89
  FirebaseInstanceID: f3f0657372592ecdfdfe2cac604a5a75758376a6
  FirebaseMessaging: 6894b8fe0a0cf26c3b13dad729f1131654ae0bdb
  FirebaseStorage: 7ca4bb7b58a25fa647b04f524033fc7cb7eb272b
  Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK: 6e529e748b45507a2ca904e0b5a52669ba3920c4
  GoogleSignIn: 7ff245e1a7b26d379099d3243a562f5747e23d39
  GoogleToolboxForMac: ff31605b7d66400dcec09bed5861689aebadda4d
  GTMSessionFetcher: 32aeca0aa144acea523e1c8e053089dec2cb98ca
  leveldb-library: 08cba283675b7ed2d99629a4bc5fd052cd2bb6a5
  lottie-ios: d699fdee68d7b63e721d949388b015fef1aaa4ac
  lottie-react-native: 216bd1295fa67b159fdbe5562a7d7b6371da6422
  nanopb: 2901f78ea1b7b4015c860c2fdd1ea2fee1a18d48
  Protobuf: 7a877b7f3e5964e3fce995e2eb323dbc6831bb5a
  QBImagePickerController: d54cf93db6decf26baf6ed3472f336ef35cae022
  React: 755b16d9a9387e856d4dce6528130c51e4d409b8
  react-native-background-timer: 1b6e6b4e10f1b74c367a1fdc3c72b67c619b222b
  react-native-fbsdk: 5c3ff4dda057e17d3b4b5491033fc653d423e71d
  RNDeviceInfo: e7c5fcde13d40e161d8a27f6c5dc69c638936002
  RNFS: c9bbde46b0d59619f8e7b735991c60e0f73d22c1
  RNImageCropPicker: e56deca5b463b9493d22e966cfd83cb1fc5c99bb
  RSKImageCropper: 98296ad26b41753f796b6898d015509598f13d97
  yoga: c3ce6137f85f60c93a834235d7f08e2b44a42eed

PODFILE CHECKSUM: a41cd15a48dcf796ca32aafef7ca99217d4a86bb

COCOAPODS: 1.6.0
```

---

### Environment

- **Platform that you're experiencing the issue on**:

  - [X ] iOS
- `react-native info`-

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  Node: 8.11.2
  Yarn: 1.9.4
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
  Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Thanks a lot for reading :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Salakar from the firebase team I could find that the issue was caused by the missing pod library for Firebase. 
So I added in my pod file :

```
pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
```

Then did a `pod install`
And launch it to the moon cause it was working :D